# Connect to kepware OPC DA using Utgard

Tags: java, opc, opc-da, kepserverex

I am using below code to make the connection from UTGARD to Kepware V6 OPC DA.

```
package com.flutura.openscada.tutorial;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException;
import org.openscada.opc.lib.common.ConnectionInformation;
import org.openscada.opc.lib.da.AccessBase;
import org.openscada.opc.lib.da.DataCallback;
import org.openscada.opc.lib.da.Item;
import org.openscada.opc.lib.da.ItemState;
import org.openscada.opc.lib.da.Server;
import org.openscada.opc.lib.da.SyncAccess;

public class UtgardTutorial1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create connection information
    final ConnectionInformation ci = new ConnectionInformation();
    ci.setHost("localhost");
    ci.setDomain("");
    ci.setUser("");
    ci.setPassword("");
    ci.setProgId("Kepware.KEPServerEX.V6\\Simulation Examples.Functions.Ramp1");

    //ci.setProgId("SWToolbox.TOPServer.V5");
    ci.setClsid("7BC0CC8E-482C-47CA-ABDC-0FE7F9C6E729"); // if ProgId is not working, try it using the Clsid instead
    final String itemId = "_System._Time_Second";
    // create a new server
    System.out.println("Server1");

    final Server server = new Server(ci, Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor());
    System.out.println("Server1 =>" + server);


    try {
        server.connect();

        final AccessBase access = new SyncAccess(server, 500);
        access.addItem(itemId, new DataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void changed(Item item, ItemState state) {
                System.out.println("Data change " + item + " : " + state);
            }

        });

        access.bind();

        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);

        access.unbind();
    } catch (final JIException e) {
        System.out.println("Errorrrrrrrr : " + String.format("%08X: %s", e.getErrorCode(), server.getErrorMessage(e.getErrorCode())));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Errorrrrrrrr : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I want to fetch data for my all the parameters in IOT Gateway from kepServer,

[image]

But to test it I have mentioned only one parameter name => Simulation Examples.Functions.Ramp1

And I am getting output like this

```
    Server1
    Server1 =>org.openscada.opc.lib.da.Server@724af044

    Sep 18, 2018 12:51:22 PM rpc.DefaultConnection processOutgoing
    INFO: 
     Sending BIND
    Sep 18, 2018 12:51:22 PM rpc.DefaultConnection processIncoming
    INFO: 
     Recieved BIND_ACK
    Sep 18, 2018 12:51:22 PM rpc.DefaultConnection processOutgoing
    INFO: 
     Sending AUTH3
    Sep 18, 2018 12:51:23 PM rpc.DefaultConnection processOutgoing
    INFO: 
     Sending ALTER_CTX
    Sep 18, 2018 12:51:23 PM rpc.DefaultConnection processIncoming
    INFO: 
     Recieved ALTER_CTX_RESP
    Sep 18, 2018 12:51:23 PM rpc.DefaultConnection processOutgoing
    Errorrrrrrrr : 00000005: Unknown error (00000005)
    INFO: 
     Sending REQUEST
    Sep 18, 2018 12:51:23 PM rpc.DefaultConnection processIncoming
            INFO: 
             Recieved FAULT
```

I am new to UTGARD code. I am not able to understand what is wrong in the code and why this error:

> 00000005: Unknown error (00000005)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @user565 No, I didn't get a solution for above code. But I used an alternative OpenOPC library of python

Comment: ok. Can you please share if you have any sample code of OpenOPC which you use in python side.

Comment: @user565 you can check on this link http://openopc.sourceforge.net/api.html